# How to specify the document type when using elasticsearch_dsl (Python)? Similarly, how to specify a few indices?

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to create this example

```
GET /my_store/products/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : { 
            "query" : {
                "match_all" : {} 
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "price" : 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using Pythons elasticsearch_dsl.

```
import elasticsearch as ES
import elasticsearch_dsl as dsl
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = ES.Elasticsearch() # i'm using the localhost default client
s = Search(using = client, index = "my_store")
```

ok, this specifies the host, port, and index.

```
s = s.filter("term", price = 20)
results = s.execute().to_dict()
```

but how do I specify the document type is "products"? Seems like there should be an argument in the Search() function.

Similar question, suppose I want to run the same query, but I want it to run over the indices "my_store" and "her_store". How do I specify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like this.

`s = Search(using=client, index=('my_report', 'my_store'), doc_type=('products'))`

Index param takes `list`, `tuple`, `string` types.

In the Search constructor you can see

```
if isinstance(index, (tuple, list)):
    self._index = list(index)
elif index:
    self._index = [index]
```

Comment: so the index field will take a tuple of strings or just a string? Will it take a list of strings?

Comment: You can use tuple or list of indexes.

Answer (score 3):

I just got it working like this:

```
client = connections.create_connection(hosts=['myNode01:9200'])
s = Search().using(client)
      .index('myindex')
      .doc_type('mytype1')
      .doc_type('mytype2')
      .query('match', name='arandomname')
```